# How to use Infomap library in PyCharm

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

How to use [infomap library](https://github.com/mapequation/infomap) in PyCharm IDE? 
I used README.md file in this path but my PyCharm IDE do not know this library via (from infomap import infomap).

Answer (score 0):

I can resolve it.
 
According to [infomap's help](http://www.mapequation.org/code.html#Examples-with-other-languages), First install swig package in your system. because i use Ubuntu I use synaptic to install it. 
 
Then follow those instructions. 
Then for Pycharm 2016.2, Follow this path:
File -> settings -> Preoject -> Project Interpreter -> select wheel icon -> select More -> then select the icon with title : show paths for the selected interpreter -> then add following path to it 
Infomap/example/python/infomap